Usage of CBOR tag 27 (major type 6)
As per specification supplied with the tag registration, one supposed to use a string as type identifier. However, the specification seems to allow a great degree of freedom wrt how to use the tag.
That is, would it be appropriate to use a non-string type to reference the type that was serialized? E.g., 27([14, [...]]), in CBOR's diagnostic notation; the 14 is the ID of serialized application-defined type.
Or should it maybe be 27([39(14), [...]]) for even better semantics? Like, although we are not using a string, as siggested by tag's spec, we explicitly tell that the first item is the ID by wrapping it inside an ID-indicating tag.
Or, if neither is good, what would be the most accurate CBOR tag (except 1010 -- it also requires a string) to indicate that this is a serialized object of type X and here is its data?
